# extract class name and add this information to another element in the dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to get a part of a class name (number) via simple html dom and add this information to another element.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="anything grd_3"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which should get:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="anything grd_3"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>*** Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That means, I need to check if there is a class 'grd_*'. If it exists, I need the number of that and add the number of stars to the first p-element of content.

**PHP:**

```
$html->find('div[class=grd_*]'); // How to search with placeholder?

// tried this one for grd_3 (how do that generally?), but it doesn't work :-(
foreach($html->find('div[class=grd_3]') as $key=>$element){
    $html->find('div[class=grd_3]',$key)->next_sibling->first_child->innertext="*** ".$element->next_sibling ->first_child->innertext;
}
```

**Update:**

```
foreach($html->find('div[class*=grd_]') as $key=>$element){
    if(($html = $html->find('[class*=grd_]', $key)) && preg_match('/grd_(\d+)/', $html->class, $m)){
            $stars = '';
            for ( $i = 0; $i <= $m[1]; $i++) $stars .= '*';
    }
    $html->find('div[class*=grd_]',$key)->next_sibling->first_child->innertext=$stars." ".$element->next_sibling ->first_child->innertext;
}
```

Comment: Don't use placeholders in class selectors. Use custom attributes instead. Like this: `<div data-grd="3">`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that you can use CSS selectors to find nodes. If those are completely supported you can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[class^='grd_'],div[class*=' grd_']`

In case they are not supported you have to either use a different html markup or iterate through all divs inside your main class and use `strpos($className, 'grd_')` to find the matching nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of regex and css:

```
if(($el = $html->find('[class*=grd_]', 0)) && preg_match('/grd_(\d+)/', $el->class, $m)){
  echo "there are " . $m[1] . " stars.";
}
```

Comment: I tried to get this in my foreach-loop, but it doesn't work. Please have a look at the updated post.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: you only need one `$html->find`